# Sequelize Join on Non Primary Key

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables I need to associate. TableA has One TableB. I'm able to do this in the TableA Model:

```
TableA.hasOne( models.TableB, { as: 'TableB', foreignKey: 'someID' } );
```

Looking at the SQL, this tries to join TableA.ID and TableB.someID. What I actually want, is to join TableA.someNonPrimaryKey and TableB.someID.

How can I tell sequelize to join with someNonPrimaryKey?

Comment: This is not possible in sequelize at the moment

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old; I am responding for the sake of others that might need the answer.

You can now associate tables on non-primary key columns. In your case, the association would be:

```
TableA.hasOne(TableB, {
  sourceKey: 'someNonPrimaryKeyColumnOnTableA',
  foreignKey: 'matchingColumnOnTableB'
});
```

Please note, the column `someNonPrimaryKeyColumnOnTableA` must have `unique` set to `true` in the model definition.

You can read more about it here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in sequelize at the moment, however you can try this way.

Difference between HasOne and BelongsTo, HasOne inserts the association key in target model whereas BelongsTo inserts the association key in the source model.
     association rather hasOne equals BelongsTo

```
TableB.belongsTo(models.TableA, { as: 'TableA', foreignKey: 'someID', targetKey: 'notTableAID' } );
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by doing both answers above from @thanh1101681 and @King James Enejo, only putting either sourcekey or targetkey didn't work!

```
TableB.belongsTo(models.TableA, { foreignKey: 'someID', targetKey: 'notTableAID' } );

TableA.hasOne(TableB, {
  sourceKey: 'someNonPrimaryKeyColumnOnTheSOurceModel',
  foreignKey: 'matchingColumnOnTheTargetModel'
});
```