# Sequelize : how to join on foreign keys

Tags: join, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and Node.js, and I need to join 2 tables on 2 foreign keys,

```
tableA.hasOne(tableB, { foreignKey: 'fk_tableB' });
tableB.belongsTo(tableA, {foreignKey: 'fk_tableB' });
```

(by the way, I don't understand the functionality of "targetKey")
but I can only obtain a join on tableA.primaryKey = tableB.fk_tableB.
How can I replace the tableA.primaryKey by tableA.fk_tableA?

I also tried to define twice tableA : in 2 different structures (one with the real primary key and the other with fk_tableA as primary key), but it's also not working (because I need the real tableA mode in another place).

Has someone an idea? Is it a bug from Sequelize?

Comment: A FK is a list of columns in one table/model whose values must apear elsewhere for a referenced/target list of columns that are PK/UNIQUE in a table. Where are you reading about 'the functionality of "targetKey" '? Please read and act on [mcve]. (Your are unclear. We don't know what you mean when you say "obtain" or "replace" or " try to define" or "not working" or "the real". And exactly what is your question?)

Comment: Ouch that was really rude ! I'm sorry if my sentence is bad, I'm not fluent, but I would try to be clearer. My question was about Sequelize and Node.js,  and how to make a join on 2 tables with Sequelize syntax, without using primary keys but 2 foreign keys. Are you agree with that ? Do you know Sequelize ?

Comment: And with regard to your comment on "targetKey", it just comes from the sequelize documentation : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#target-keys,I hoped this functionality could have done the job, that's all.

Comment: I don't know why you think it is rude to tell someone they are unclear when they are unclear or tell them to (please) read and follow the site's rules which if not followed get their question closed for lack of necessary info. The lack of clarity is not related to fluency. It is because you are choosing words that presumably apply but don't communicate to others what it is they are applicable to. Please show all the code, input & output you are talking about. PS You can join on any columns, it doesn't matter whether they are PKs or FKs in their tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize Join on Non Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974021/sequelize-join-on-non-primary-key)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I replace the tableA.primaryKey by tableA.fk_tableA?

There is no tableA.fk_tableA. But if there were, we would expect you to have named it that because column tableA.fk_tableA is a FK to a key column in tableA. Because that's the convention for naming a column fk_tableA. Similarly we would expect a belongTo like yours that adds a column that is a FK to the tableA PK to call it fk_tableA, not fk_tableB. Just like your hasOne gives tableA a column fk_tableB to the tableB PK. (If you want a FK to be to some other column than the PK then you say so via targetKey.)

If you so named FKs after their target table, you seem to want tableA.fk_tableB = tableB.fk_tableA. The way you have named them now, you seem to want tableA.fk_tableB = tableB.fk_tableB.

> I need to join 2 tables on 2 foreign keys

It is *extremely unlikely* that you need the join above. Declaring a column to be a FK says that a value of the source/referencing column is always a value of the target/referenced column. Here targets are PKs. Such a join on a FK to one table and a FK to another table will only return rows that share the same PK value, even though the PKs are from different tables.

Comment: I know it is really not recommended to join on foreign keys, but I can't do otherwise (no possibility to change the database model). I found explanations to my problem in this equivalent subject -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974021/sequelize-join-on-non-primary-key. Thanks

Comment: That comment is also unintelligible & I have no idea what you want to do. Good luck.